# htaccess redirect for dynamic urls not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I basically want:

http://example.com/index.php?page=abc to redirect to http://www.exmaple.com/abc

I have:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ %1? [R=301]
RewriteRule ^%1$ index.php?page=%1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Some syntax issues in your 2nd rule and logic ones in your 1st rule.

Following should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

# for external redirection from `/index.php?page=abc` to `/abc`
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

# for internal redirection from `/abc` to `/index.php?page=abc`
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

#### PS: I suggest you to read: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)